# SwiftUI error - "Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError:"

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-location, appdelegate

I'm trying to implement MapKit and CoreLocation in SwiftUI to fetch user locations in my app, check permissions, handle errors etc.. but I'm getting this error when I run the simulator and grant location permission.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated

[Here's a screenshot with where the error message shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O5jy.png)

And here's my code which I presume is missing something that's causing the error:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

// All Map data goes here

class MapViewModel: NSObject,ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    
    @Published var mapView = MKMapView()
    
    // Region...
    @Published var region : MKCoordinateRegion!
    // Based on location it will set up...
    
    // Alert...
    @Published var permissionDenied = false
    
    // Map Type...
    @Published var mapType : MKMapType = .standard
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        
        // Checking permissions...
        
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .denied:
            // Alert...
            permissionDenied.toggle()
        case .notDetermined:
            // Requesting...
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            // If permission given...
            manager.requestLocation()
        default:
            ()
        }
    }
    
func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        
        // Error...
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    // Getting user Region...
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:
                         [CLLocation]) {
        
        guard let location = locations.last else {return}
        
        self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
        
        // Updating Map...
        self.mapView.setRegion(self.region, animated: true)
         
        // Smooth animation...
        self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(self.mapView.visibleMapRect, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager,
```

should be

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
```